# Is an "independent" floating window possible in a UWP application?

Tags: c#, uwp

`MainPage.xaml` is the default window created where all your other windows and content is "housed" within when you create a new `UWP` project. For instance, I can toggle between pages held within `MainPage.xaml`.

Is it possible to have an independent window in a project, i.e:  the window can be moved outside `MainPage.xaml`, and anywhere on your PC's screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is an "independent" floating window possible in a UWP application?

Sure, you could show multiple views for an app in UWP platform. here is [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/layout/show-multiple-views) that you could refer to. And both AppWindow and ApplicationView class could be use to show multiple views.

Comment: [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/appwindow/) microsoft example of `AppWindow` notes in a comment in the code "Only ever create one window".  In the `MSDN` `AppWindow` docs [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.windowmanagement.appwindow?view=winrt-22000) it sounds like multiple windows is possible though?  Whereas the `ApplicationView` docs more formally notes you can have up to four windows simultaneously, [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview?view=winrt-22000) ?

Comment: You could make more than one AppWindow  in UWP app.